# Pydoc not working in Python 3.3 in Windows

Tags: python, pydoc

I am trying to generate the help text at runtime and i am not able to use the pydoc command in Windows. When i type

```
>>> pydoc(atexit)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pydoc' is not defined
```

I have already set up the environment variables for `pydoc.py` file. `C:\Python33\Lib\pydoc.py`.

This also not works like it works for `>>help('atexit')`

```
>>> pydoc('atexit')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pydoc' is not defined
```

Whats the possible reason for it.

Updates:

```
>>> import pydoc
>>> pydoc(sys)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
>>> pydoc('sys')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: I'm not too sure, but isn't pydoc more like a script than a module to be imported? `$ pydoc sys` works just fine, and it looks like that is what pydoc is for.

Comment: see the below answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like any library in Python, you need to import it before you can use it.

**Edit** What exactly are you trying to achieve? Modules are indeed not callable. `pydoc.help` is the function you want, although I don't really know why you need it, since as you note the standalone `help` function does the same thing already.